# Use dynamic adapterLocale in localizationProvider

Tags: javascript, locale, dayjs

How to change the `adapterLocale` dynamically based on the region? If I want to have German locale, I can use:

```
import 'dayjs/locale/de'

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale={'de'}>
{children}
</>
```

But is there any way to make it more adaptive to use the current locale?